Change GeoTIFF / COG Area_OR_POINT Metadata Parameter
I want to change the gdal metadata parameter "AREA_OR_POINT" of a GeoTiff or COG file. I start with the GeoTiff and process it into a COG, so it does not matter at what point the parameter is updated.
I tried it with gdal_translate, and there with the -mo parameter to change metadata properties, but then the coordinates do not adapt.

could you provide like the gdal command you tried ?
Also, I don't understand what you mean by the coordinate not adapting ?
If you expected a change in georeferencing, the AREA_OR_POINT metadata does not influence it

Answered on the gdal-dev mailing list https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2019-December/051343.html
Use gdal_edit https://gdal.org/en/latest/programs/gdal_edit.html. If you only want to change the metadata without changing the georeferencing, use
gdal_edit -mo AREA_OR_POINT=Point point.tif

If you also need to change the georeferencing by half-a-pixel shifts, use
gdal_edit -mo AREA_OR_POINT=Point point.tif --config GTIFF_POINT_GEO_IGNORE YES 

If the aim is to change the interpretation from point to area, then use -mo AREA_OR_POINT=Area.
